# Using WPDB in standalone script?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to connect to WordPress using the WPDB because it's such a beautiful class and also there are configurations that specified in wp-config.php so i won't need to specify it again.

I going to write a small separated script from main WordPress to run in background that will need to use this WPDB instance.

How can I archive this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The best(fastest and safest) way to load only load the core functionality of WordPress is to use the `SHORTINIT` flag like this:

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );

require( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );

//Here you can use WordPress core features, for example the $WPDB object
```

For more information about this and see what is loaded, is to check the code in `/wp-settings.php`. There you will find the following section:

```
// Stop most of WordPress from being loaded if we just want the basics.
if ( SHORTINIT )
    return false;
```

This means that anything after this won't be loaded, and it's quite a lot of things as you can see. The footprint will be much smaller than just loading the `wp-load.php` and still gives you access to all the all the built in functions in WordPress core, unlike including for example `/wp-includes/wp-db.php` directly. Many functions in WP core also has dependencies in other files and it can be a mess to figure out exactly what files you need to include to be able do what you want. `SHORTINIT` includes the needed dependencies so you don't have to worry about this.

If you know exactly what you need, for example only WPDB, the fastest way is of course to only include the files you need, but `SHORTINIT` provides a safer and more standardised way to load the WP core and the dependencies. With `SHORTINIT` WordPress does not load plugins, most parts of the plugin API, themes, theme functions and most admin and frontend functions. This is where the heavy code is in a typical WordPress install. 
In most cases I think `SHORTINIT` is worth the small tradeoff in speed/performance compared to including only the files you need and it's in most cases a huge performance boost compared to a full load.

Comment: That's definitively the best answer!

Comment: By far the best answer using SHORTINIT for custom scripts is a LOT faster.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. wp-db.php itself requires some extraneous WP functions that don't get included and this solves that.

Comment: I tried this and found that it changed my timezone setting. I looked into `wp-settings.php` and found this: `date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );` Quite annoying. What worries me most is that I don't know what else might also be affected.

Answer (score 54):

Indeed `SHORTINIT` seems like the best solution: see @Pelmered [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25158840/97433)...

**For reference:** `SHORTINIT` was introduced in WordPress 3.0 ([June 17, 2010](https://wordpress.org/support/wordpress-version/version-3-0/)), despite not being mentioned in the release notes, having a [look at the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0/wp-settings.php#L93) itself provides clear indication of its addition.

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

// $wpdb is available, do stuff
```

Comment: Isn't `wp-load.php` enough?

Comment: Yes, wp-load is enough by itself, it loads all the rest - in other words, this is loading all of WordPress including all plugins.

Comment: When I use @farinspace code (with 2 or more `include_once()` or `require()`) in functions.php, I get `internal server error 500`!. Only one `include` or `require` works for me!

Answer (score 23):

WordPress actually allows you to use your own DBA (database abstraction layer) just by creating a file called `db.php` and saving it in the root of your `wp-content` directory.

I had the problem of needing to access a database via class I wrote, that had nothing todo with WordPress, but I didn't want to create a whole new DBA just go with this script.

Since the default `WPDB` does not allow you to use the factory pattern, I quickly wrote a few lines to support it, and added it to `db.php`...

```
<?php

class DB extends wpdb
{
  protected static $instance = null;

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if (!self::$instance) {
      self::$instance = new DB(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }
}

$wpdb = DB::getInstance();
```

Now when needing to use `wpdb` from elsewhere (in my case a non-WordPress class), you can juse use:

```
$wpdb = DB::getInstance();
```

from within a method, rather than the horrible `global`.

Comment: beautiful way of getting $wpdb

Comment: Wow, where can I learn more about WordPress' DBA and db.php file?

Comment: The problem with this is the code still calls WordPress functions like apply_filter. I'm trying to find a way around having to include any other extraneous PHP files (or the whole thing).

Comment: I don't understand. How do you use it? Using the db.php file like you said from a non-WP script (as asked by the question) will get `Fatal error: Class 'wpdb' not found`

Answer (score 18):

You can use `$wpdb` in new `.php` file which is inside of theme folder, by using following code.

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$my_url = explode('wp-content' , $url); 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$my_url[0];

include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

global $wpdb;
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this is the only way mentioned here of loading the minimum code to just use wpdb, without loading all of WordPress...

Answer (score 5):

You should just `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');`

And then you all WordPress classes, hooks and everything will be loaded. Now you can start to interact with the database using `global $wpdb;` and the wpdb instance will be started.

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to include the wp-load.php file into your script.

```
require('the/path/to/wp-load.php file');
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick too:

```
  preg_match('/^(.+)wp-content\/.*/', dirname(__FILE__), $path);
  include($path[1] . 'wp-load.php');
```

Comment: Hi Hamid Araghi, basically this is not a big deal. The preg_match of dirname(__FILE__) is stored into segments into the variable $path. The tricky part can be the preg_match parameters if you are not using it too often. Please see here for a good way of testing and a cheat-sheet for the parameters at the bottom of the page: https://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Following two steps are enough.

1. Include the wp-blog-header.php file
2. Before using the $wpdb, put as global $wpdb;

any global variables you can use in this page after that. Make sure you give the correct include path of wp-blog-header.php. No need to include several files.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and lightweight way with just a single line is

require(dirname(**_FILE__**).'/wp-blog-header.php');

Reason is because WordPress initializes loading the index.php and when you check the index.php , you see :

require(dirname(**__FILE__**).'/wp-blog-header.php');

This loads and bootstrap WordPress.

so to use WordPress outside of the WordPress install , simply create a new file and then write :

require(dirname(**__FILE__**).'/wp-blog-header.php');

then for a test, write : global $wpdb; var_export($wpdb) .

so now you have access to all WordPress API and the database object $wpdb.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 21st, 2021 this was in their documentation, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/, and it worked seamlessly for me:

```
$wpdb = $GLOBALS['wpdb'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Include the WordPress bootstrap file
require_once('/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php');

// Access the global $wpdb object
global $wpdb;

// Use $wpdb to execute a SQL query
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM my_table");

// Display the results
foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo $row->column_name;
}
?>
```