# Can't use wordpress functions in custom php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a custom php function for Wordpress that a custom Java program can access, the problem is anytime I try to use a WP function such as `wp_hash_password` it fails and returns a `filenotfoundException`.

The custom php file is sitting on the root directory of my wordpress installation and I have put

```
require(ABSPATH. 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
```

at the top of the file so it would know where to find the function.

Am I missing something?  Because even with the above file included, it is still failing.

IF I take out all wordpress functions it 'works'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ABSPATH` is defined in `wp-config.php` - you'd have to `require` that as well.

I haven't tried it, but [this page](http://blog.getcs.com/2011/03/create-stand-alone-web-pages-or-widgets-that-use-wordpress-functions/) may help.  Though according to the comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331944/1714), just including `wp-load.php` may do the trick.

Comment: Thank you 100000000000 times.  I would have never though to ask or search for those terms.  I'm doing this on android and that is where my mind was.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in addition for easier inclusion:

```
preg_match('/^(.+)wp-content\/.*/', dirname(__FILE__), $path);
include($path[1] . 'wp-load.php');
```