# How to make the second file of my plugin part of the WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin which has just one setting which is set with `add_option('myinfo')` in my main plugin php file. However, I have a second php file which is almost freestanding, except that I want it to get that setting. I tried using `get_option('myinfo')`, which works in the first file, but in the second file, it gives this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_option()`

Basically, I think that my second php file is totally outside of WordPress. No WordPress specific code works, it just acts like some regular php file. How can I get the php file to have access to the WordPress database?

The file is mostly standalone, all it does is respond to an Ajax request, but I just want it to have this one piece of data from my plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [this page](http://blog.makingsense.com/2011/03/create-stand-alone-web-pages-or-widgets-that-use-wordpress-functions/) gives some details of how to include WordPress functions in a standalone page.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script/) covers some of the same ideas.