# Call to undefined function, get_settings wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, undefined

I have a Wordpress plugin with index.php that contains this line of code:

```
$plugindir = get_settings('home').'/wp-content/plugins/'.dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
```

When I echo that code I get this output:

my.site.nl/wp-content/plugins/Tutorials

On the index page I also have a button that redirects to uploader.php,
inside uploader.php I have this code:

```
$plugindir = get_settings('home').'/wp-content/plugins/'.dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
```

When I run the program I get an error that says:

Call to undefined function get_settings()

This error only applies on uploader.php, index.php works fine!

So it seems that I have to somehow let the uploader.php know that get_settings is a Wordpress function and it should recognize it, but I don't know how and I also don't know why the index page runs fine with the same code without including anything. I hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index.php` brings in all the WordPress functions as it loads.  If you're loading another PHP file directly, you'll need to load in the WordPress functions by calling `wp-load.php`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script/5331944#5331944) (and the comments - you don't need to load all the files the answer mentions).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use get_option('home') in place of get_settings('home') it may work.

Comment: Haven't tried because of the other answer but thanks anyways :)