# Associating a file with WordPress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have created a WordPress plugin named album-plugin, and here's my plugin structure

```
wp-content
---plugin
   --album-plugin
      --album-plugin.php
      --ajax_work.php
      --add_album.php
      --edit_album.php
      --js
      --css
```

Now here's the total script of my album-plugin.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Album Pluggin

*/
define( 'MYPLUGINNAME_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_album_pluggin_activate' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_album_pluggin_deactivate' );


function my_album_pluggin_activate(){
    //Activation method.
    activate_album_pluggin();
}

function my_album_pluggin_deactivate(){
    //Deactivation method.
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query(" DROP TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."album ");
        $wpdb->query(" DROP TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."image ");
}



add_action('init', 'add_ajax_work');
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_album_menu_page');

function add_ajax_work()
{
    include 'ajax_work.php';
}

function register_custom_album_menu_page() {
  add_menu_page( 'Album Menu Display', 'Album Menu', 'read', 'album-menu', 'display_album_panel' /*, $icon_url, $position*/ );
  add_submenu_page( 'album-menu', 'Add Album', 'Add Album','read', 'add-album','display_album_subpanel_add');
  add_submenu_page( 'album-menu', 'Edit Album', 'Edit Album','read', 'edit-album','display_album_subpanel_edit');
} 





if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='add_album'){
    submit_album_form();
}


if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='updateRecordsListings')
{
    include 'reorder.php';
}







function header_album_css_page() {

    wp_register_style($handle = 'header-css', $src = plugins_url('css/album_style.css', __FILE__), $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');

    wp_enqueue_style('header-css');
}

add_action('init', 'header_album_css_page');

function reorder_album_css_page() {

    wp_register_style($handle = 'reorder-css', $src = plugins_url('css/reorder_style.css', __FILE__), $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');

    wp_enqueue_style('reorder-css');
}

add_action('init', 'reorder_album_css_page');


function display_album_panel()
{  
    global $wpdb;
    $banner_list = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."album order by album_order desc");
    ?>
    <div class='admin-custom'>
    <?php  include 'view_album.php'; ?>  

     </div>


<?php
}
function display_album_subpanel_add()
{   ?>
    <div class='admin-custom'>
    <?php  include 'add_album.php'; ?>  

     </div>
    <?php 

}
function display_album_subpanel_edit()
{   
    global $wpdb;
    $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."album ORDER BY album_order ASC");
    ?>
    <div class='admin-custom'>
    <?php  include 'edit_album.php'; ?>  

     </div>
    <?php 

}
/*add_shortcode('DISPLAY-BANNER-SLIDER','func_display_banner');

function func_display_banner(){
        global $wpdb;

        $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."banner ORDER BY banner_order DESC");
        $path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/banner-pluggin/banner/';



        $html = '<!-- banner slider-->
                                    <div id="header">
                                       <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                                       <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">';
        foreach($res as $row){ 

        $html .='<img src="'.plugins_url().'/banner-pluggin/banner/'. $row->banner_img  .'" alt="" title="'.$row->banner_content.'">';

        }

        $html .= '</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>        
                                    <!--//slider-->';
    return $html;   
}*/

function activate_album_pluggin(){
    global $wpdb;
        /*if(!file_exists(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/banner-pluggin/banner/'))
                        mkdir(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/banner-pluggin/banner/');*/

    $sql_album  = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$wpdb->prefix."album (
            album_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
            album_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
                        album_slug VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
            album_content TEXT NOT NULL ,
            album_order INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        album_timestamp VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL

        )";
    $sql_image = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$wpdb->prefix."image (
            image_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
            image_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
                        image_slug VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
            image_img VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
            image_content TEXT NOT NULL ,
            album_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        image_order INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        image_status INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        image_timestamp VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL
        )"; 
    $wpdb->query($sql_album);
        $wpdb->query($sql_image);
}

function submit_album_form(){
    global $wpdb;



    $albumname = $_POST['album_name'];
        $albumcontent = $_POST['album_content'];
        $albumtimestamp = time();
    $imagename = $_POST['image_name'];

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $wpdb->prefix."album", 
        array( 
            'album_name' => $albumname, 
            'album_content' => $albumcontent,
                        'album_timestamp' => $albumtimestamp

                    ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
                        '%s', 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
        $album_info = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."album WHERE album_timestamp='".$albumtimestamp."'");
    foreach($album_info as $row)
        {
            $id=$row->album_id;
        }
        $albumslug=$id."-".make_slug($albumname);
        $update_data=array(
                            'album_slug'=>$albumslug
                          );
        if(!file_exists(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/'))
                        mkdir(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/');
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["album_img"]["tmp_name"],ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/' . $_FILES["album_img"]["name"]))
                echo "done";
        else
                echo "error";
        $wpdb->update(
                        $wpdb->prefix."album", // Table
                        $update_data, // Array of key(col) => val(value to update to)
                        array(
                            'album_timestamp' => $albumtimestamp
                             ) // Where
                     );




        $image_link='wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/'. $_FILES["album_img"]["name"];
        $image_timestamp=intval(time()+10);
        $wpdb->insert( 
        $wpdb->prefix."image", 
        array( 
            'image_name' => $imagename, 
            'album_id' => $id,
                        'image_img'=>$image_link,
                        'image_timestamp' => $image_timestamp

                    ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
                        '%d',
                        '%s', 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
        $image_info = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."image WHERE image_timestamp='".$image_timestamp."'");
    foreach($image_info as $irow)
        {
            $i_id=$irow->image_id;
        }
        $imageslug=$id."-".make_slug($imagename);
        $update_image_data=array(
                            'image_slug'=>$imageslug
                          );
        $wpdb->update(
                        $wpdb->prefix."image", // Table
                        $update_image_data, // Array of key(col) => val(value to update to)
                        array(
                            'image_timestamp' => $image_timestamp
                             ) // Where
                     );


}

function make_slug($data)
     {
         $data_slug = trim($data," ");
         $search = array('/','\\',':',';','!','@','#','$','%','^','*','(',')','_','+','=','|','{','}','[',']','"',"'",'<','>',',','?','~','`','&',' ','.');
         $data_slug = str_replace($search, "_", $data_slug);
         return $data_slug;
     }


    ?>
```

now here's my edit_album.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/album-pluggin/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function get_album_data(album_id)
{
    alert(album_id);
    $.post("<?php echo plugins_url();?>/album-pluggin/ajax_work.php",
                                                       {'album_id':album_id},
                                                        function(data)
                                                            {
                                                                alert(data);
                                                            }
                                                      );
}
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Add Album</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input name="action" type="hidden" value="edit_album"/>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Select Album</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <select class="text_data" name="album_id" onchange="get_album_data(this.value);">
                <option value="0">Select Album</option>
                <?php
                foreach($res as $r)
                {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $r->album_id;?>"><?php echo $r->album_name;?></option>
                <?php
                }?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Album Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <input class="text_data" name="album_name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Album Image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <input name="album_img" type="file"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Image Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <input name="image_name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
           <span class="label_data">Album content</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <textarea class="textarea_data" name="album_content" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add Banner">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the last ajax_work.php

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $album_id=$_POST['album_id'];
    $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."album WHERE album_id='$album_id'");
    echo $res;
?>
```

The issue is that the ajax is working all perfect, the problem is that it alerts the message:

```
 <br />
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  
Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\odishi\wp-content\plugins\album-pluggin\ajax_work.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

It seems that the portion of the script

```
global $wpdb;
        $album_id=$_POST['album_id'];
        $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."album WHERE album_id='$album_id'");
```

is having some problem.

Comment: I don't understand your `add_ajax_work()` function - you're calling `ajax_work.php` directly from your javascript, so I don't see why it's needed.  If you do need to call it directly, you probably need to include `wp-load.php` - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script/5331944#5331944)

Comment: One other thing - `ajax_work.php` is a classic example of SQL injection - maybe `$album_id=(int)$_POST['album_id'];` instead?