# how to get id and location of attachment image in wordpress using php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

here i using external database to get image location by using ID  - i have external file called process.php

here is example for database table

http://im33.gulfup.com/M9OCy.png

and here is php code that i using and working fine

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM titoex WHERE id=$GetPicId") or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query);

$PicLocation =$result['location'];
```

i need to make it with wordpress , if i upload image with wordpress  attachment i can get it by id too i was trying to search in wordpress database but i can`t find table , i really need some help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stored in the `$wpdb->posts` (usually `wp_posts`) table.  But if you have the ID, the easiest option will be to use the [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) function, which returns an array with the image url, width and height.

If you just need it as an `img` tag ready for output, you could use the [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) function.

Comment: i using external php file and all i need just image location

Comment: Do you mind loading WordPress code in your file?  You could call `wp-load.php` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script/5331944#5331944) and call the function I mentioned.