# create a wordpress file with all functionality

Tags: wordpress

hello I would like to create a file that will generate a customized xml with my products,
I have no problems creating the xml,
but I want to connect to the db and perform a query using the WP built in functionality.

How do I do that? for example I add this file buildXml.php
to the project folder.

```
<?php
//buildXml.php

require(WORDPRESS_FUNCTIONALITY);

// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo 'stuff';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you should be able to call `wp-load.php` (as per the comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script/5331944#5331944)).