# WordPress variables don't work in its own php file

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I wrote my own PHP file and include it to Wordpress using:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/rewrite-urls-wordpress

But now if i try in this file use Wordpress variable or function (for example get_header();) i see only blank screen. I understand that this file can not use these variables but how can i link this file with Wordpress?

I think it is simple and i tried to find answer but i don't know how to name that. Can you please help me?

I see this error reason:
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home1/colleie6/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatads/filter.php on line 9

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP file, refresh page, tell us the errors that it shows

Comment: I added that to main question - thank you.

Comment: How is this file being loaded? What is the URL that you access it with? `filter.php` is not a file that gets loaded by default logic, how/where is that being included?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try including `wp-load.php`, as outlined on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331944/1714) (as per the comments, you don't need the other files).

**EDIT**

As per the comment from [Steve Buzonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816584/steve-buzonas), this answer's wrong for your particular situation.  I missed the mention of the tutorial, and thought you had a standalone page (much like the other question I linked to).  Sadly, since it's the accepted answer, I can't delete it.

Looking at the tutorial, it looks like the code should be added to your theme's `functions.php` (though I'm tempting fate by not testing it).

Comment: The tutorial linked discusses hooking in to wordpress to add functionality, the path of the file is a theme file and should already have wordpress loaded. Including `wp-load.php` is generally a bad way to do things unless you have significantly custom logic, such as an entirely separate code base that has some interaction with wordpress.

Comment: Fair point - I missed the mention of the tutorial.  You're right - I've suggested probably the worst possible way to do this.  I had thought it was a standalone PHP file.  Looks like the code it mentions should be in the theme's `functions.php`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to access WordPress native functions in external PHP file is including 'wp-blog-header.php' file into your external PHP file:

```
e.g. require_once('wp-blog-header.php'); //make sure to change the path according to your external file location
```

Comment: If you are requiring `wp-blog-header.php`, which is what `index.php` does to bootstrap wordpress, you should `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);`.