# Query Wordpress Database outside of Wordpress files

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to access my Wordpress database from a file that is outside of the theme files.  However, I can't directly use the wp-config information because they change every day.  This results in the necessity of the global $wpdb variable.

Could anyone provide some assistance in the way of accessing the database?

Here's my code trying to gain access :

```
<?php

 define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');


 global $wpdb;

?>
```

...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['post_variable'])) {
$selected_post = $_POST['post_variable'];
}

elseif(isset($_GET['post_variable'])) {
$selected_post = $_GET['post_variable'];
}


$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'home-messages' AND ID = '$selected_post'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
$display_post_content = $row1['post_content'];
$display_post_title = $row1['post_title'];

}
?>
```

Comment: just load wp and use wpdb or if you really must require the config file and use the settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WPDB in standalone script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script)

Answer (score 0):

I think  you need to use `mysql_connect`, with the global $wpdb use the WordPress sql method.