# Adding wordpress menu items or wordpress plugins to a side page that is not wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, wordpress

I currently have a Wordpress website and have a page in the site that is not Wordpress.  I have an admin menu on this page that connects back to mysql and I have a plugin installed on Wordpress that I would like to be accessed inside of this non wordpress page.  They both use the same sql database.  The page that is not a wordpress page is html, php.  I am just wondering how I can do this.  Thank you.

Comment: You have to include wp-load.php file on php page.
Some thing is shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script

Comment: Is the "adding WordPress menu items to a non WordPress page" related to "accessing the WordPress plugin from a non WordPress page"? Do you know about AJAX and WordPress?

Comment: I do not know about AJAX and Wordpress.  Also, I would say that it could be related to accessing the Wordpress plugin from a non Wordpress page.

Comment: I still don't quite understand exactly what you are trying to do but you can run the plugin code using an AJAX request from a non WordPress page. This is much, much easier than the approach suggested by milan kyada since the WordPress AJAX handler will load the WordPress core for you.