# How to include $wpdb into ob_start()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a simplistic PHP playground plugin to run PHP without saving it, but if I write `global $wpdb;` in the playground it's null. I have tried including it before the code actually ran but it's still null.

This is my code that executes the PHP code:

```php
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['code'] ) ) {
    ob_start();
    eval( $_POST['code'] );
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $output;
}
```

So, how I am supposed to include `$wpdb` to be able to use it within the PHP editor?

Comment: Looks like a security nightmare.

Comment: It is, but I mean, If the plugin is used only by administrators and it's used under "their own risk" how is that a nightmare?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script